# Add ID to Button in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, spynner

I'm currently trying to find a way to add an ID to an html button using a javascript injection. The html is simple and looks like this:

```
<button type="submit" class="submit btn primary-btn" tabindex="4">Sign in</button>
```

Now, as you can see, it doesn't have an ID or a name, making it a bit difficult to find using spynner in Python. What javascript could I inject to add an ID to this script? Would having javascript search for that entire string and then replace the entire string with an ID added ot it? Or is there a better way of going about it?

Comment: Use jquery to select the element and then use $(selector).attr('id', 'value'); to add an ID

Comment: Is there only one button on the page with the text `Sign in` or anything that is unique to the button?

Comment: The correct solution is to make the `button` uniquely identifiable by assigning it an ID at source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To ensure html integrity I would suggest:

```
$('.submit.btn.primary-btn').eq(0).attr('id', 'foobar');
```

Comment: no need for that if statement. `$('.submit.btn.primary-btn').eq(0).attr('id', 'foobar');` works fine even when there are no elements.

Comment: This one worked the best of me, the eq selector made it so simple. Thank you! :D

Comment: im glad it helped you :-) eq is quite useful when you need to access a specific index within a selector

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".submit.btn.primary-btn").attr("id", "foobar");
```

Comment: This will work only if the `button` is the only element with those classes.

Comment: @BlakePlumb: No, it will always "work". It will just affect other elements, too.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to be sure to affect just that element, do like:

```
$('button[tabindex="4"]').attr('id', 'value');
```

By the way, it makes no much sense to add an ID at runtime: if you can refer to the element, you shouldn't need the attribute anymore.

Comment: How does this make it "sure"?

Comment: I was pretty sure that `tabindex` should be unique - well, then it's just "highly likely" : PP

Comment: It works as long as there is exactly 4 inputs in the form, could it be safer to filter on the [type="submit"] attribute ?